# DevExpress printing labelBrick in every report

Tags: vb.net, report, devexpress

Hello I am having problems with reports of Devexpress, I need to include a label vertically in all pages of report like watermark in the left margin. I see this example of devexpress but is too poor and not is dinamically because the text of the label is not fixed and I charge from database and can change the lenght

https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t457705/how-to-add-a-brick-with-vertical-text-to-the-margin-of-each-report-page

For example to see correctly I need to do all this calculations

```
 Private Function CreateLabel(ByVal oReport As DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport, ByVal page As Page, ByVal _fFuente As Font, ByVal _tamanio As SizeF, ByVal _sTexto As String) As LabelBrick
        Dim labelBrick As New LabelBrick() With {.Angle = 90, .Font = _fFuente, .Text = _sTexto, .CanShrinkAndGrow = False}
        'Para utilizar el margen derecho
        'New PointF(page.Size.Width + (page.MarginsF.Left), ((page.Size.Height - _tamanio.Width) / 2) + page.MarginsF.Top)
        'Para utilizar el margen izquierdo
        'New PointF((page.MarginsF.Left) / 2, ((page.Size.Height - _tamanio.Width) / 2) + page.MarginsF.Top)

        Dim tamanioBrick As New SizeF(_tamanio.Height + _fFuente.Size * 6, _tamanio.Width * 3)
        Dim posicionBrick As New PointF((page.MarginsF.Left) / 3, ((page.Size.Height - tamanioBrick.Width) / 2) + page.MarginsF.Top)
        labelBrick.Initialize(oReport.PrintingSystem, New RectangleF(posicionBrick, tamanioBrick))
        labelBrick.Style.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.MiddleLeft

        Return labelBrick
    End Function
```

¿Any ocurrence to solve my problem?

I need a vertical label in the margin of all documents

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Page.AddBrick(VisualBrick)](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraPrinting.Page.AddBrick(DevExpress.XtraPrinting.VisualBrick)) method to achieve this goal.

The idea is to create a report document, handle its `AfterPrint` event, iterate through all report pages (`XtraReport.PrintingSystem.Pages`) and call this method to add a brick to the specified position within a page. I have found this info in [this ticket](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t661716/html5-document-viewer-a-brick-added-to-the-page-on-the-report-s-afterprint-event-is-not#). Also, a sample code is available in the [AfterPrint](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.AfterPrint) help topic.